# Conservative force as negative gradient of scalar potential

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, potential-energy, conservative-field

In Classical Mechanics by H. Goldstein it is mentioned that

> “To satisfy the strong law of action and reaction, $V_{ij}$ can be a function only of the distance between the particles $i$ and $j$, i.e. $V_{ij} = V_{ij}(|r_i-r_j|)$.”

I am asking why the potential here can be a function of only the distance between particles $i$ and $j$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conservative force as a potencial energy gradient](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141715/)

Comment: What other variables are you wondering about?

Comment: Unless you tell us what your definition of "conservative force" is, this question is unanswerable.